# How to avoid sort when using a composite index?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

Create a test table:

```
create table customer (first_name varchar2(20), last_name varchar2(20) not null, address varchar(20));

insert into customer select dbms_random.string('U', 20), dbms_random.string('U', 20), dbms_random.string('U', 20) from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;

create index i_ln_fn_0 on customer(last_name, first_name,0); — just to be sure that all rows are indexed
```

Now the explain plan:

```
explain plan for
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(20) */ *
  from CUSTOMER
  where first_name like 'AB%'
    and first_name is not null
  order by last_name;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |   197 | 12411 |   275   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |          |   197 | 12411 |   275   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CUSTOMER |   197 | 12411 |   274   (1)| 00:00:04 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("FIRST_NAME" LIKE 'AB%' AND "FIRST_NAME" IS NOT NULL)
```

But as I want only the first rows, I'd like to avoid the sort of the whole table. I'd like to have a plan like this:

```
SELECT STATEMENT
    TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID (customer)
        INDEX FULL SCAN (i_ln_fn_0)
```

How to persuade the db to avoid the sort?

The problem is even worse. Even when I use the last_name only, everywhere:

```
explain plan for
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(20) */ last_name
  from CUSTOMER
  where last_name like 'AB%'
    and last_name is not null
  order by last_name;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |    17 |   357 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY    |           |    17 |   357 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| I_LN_FN_0 |    17 |   357 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("LAST_NAME" LIKE 'AB%')
       filter("LAST_NAME" LIKE 'AB%')
```

Here the sort is really not necessary, but the db still uses it. Why?

**Edit:** Tested on both

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

and

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production+
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production+
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0Production"+
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production+
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production+
```

with the same plan.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results.  In fact, I get the plan you're looking for, with an `INDEX FULL SCAN`.  Exactly what version of Oracle are you using?  Did you leave out any statistics gathering?  It's odd that you don't get `dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)` in the Predicate Information section.  Did you change the parameter optimizer_dynamic_sampling to 0?

Comment: Strange, because I can reproduce the problem on both my personal (on my notebook) and the production databases (I added the db versions to the original question). The databases do not contain any unusual tweaks, as far as I can tell. Everything important has default values in V$PARAMETER, optimizer_dynamic_sampling=2. I re-gathered statistics with `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('TEST','CUSTOMER',cascade=>true);` but without any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was in wrong value of NLS_SORT param. After changing it to BINARY, the plans began to look like I wanted.

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams152.htm:

> The value of NLS_SORT affects execution plans of queries. Because a
>   standard index cannot be used as a source of values sorted in a
>   linguistic order, an explicit sort operation must usually be performed
>   instead of an index range scan. A functional index on the NLSSORT
>   function may be defined to provide values sorted in a linguistic order
>   and reintroduce the index range scan to the execution plan.

(I've got this answer from Paul Horth in forums.oracle com.)